# BIRT how to get value outside column

Tags: css, birt

I'm trying to create a BIRT report about a productline.
This productline is a table, existing of 3 columns.
The first column contains the name of the product, the 2nd one a product scale and the last one a MSRP. My table looks like the following:
[image]

Because product description is normally longer than the product name, it's wrapped to the column borders. Now what I want to do is that this description just passes the column border, because it's the only element on that line.

Please note that creating another detail row isn't a solution for this case.

In CSS you can achieve this by using `position: absolute;` . I didn't find yet how to do this in BIRT, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the empty cell under MSRP then slide to the product description cell. Then right click on the empty cell and select merge cell

[image]